# What is the path to yarn error log files?

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I'm migrating our gitlab CI script to yarn from npm and have the following line that saves npm error logs for 1 day:

```yaml
artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  paths:
    - /root/.npm/_logs/
```

My question is, **what is the corresponding path for yarn error logs?**

I have found the following two docs for yarn but neither says anything about error logs and searching the yarn docs yield nothing.

- Continuous Integration (https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install-ci/#gitlab)
- Migrating from npm (https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there is a `yarn` error, a `yarn-error.log` file is created at the root directory of your project.

There [seems](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyarnpkg.com+%22yarn-error.log%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyarnpkg.com+%22yarn-error.log%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10599j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to be no official documentation about this. But you can find the code [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/d4805c302d9a02fd2a52cb4e02f9092b4689fbb1/src/cli/index.js#L497).